# .htaccess URL Rewrite in Farsi

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have converted a classified script to RTL to be able to use it with Farsi character sets. Everything is working perfectly except that my `.htaccess` is not writing my ad titles that are supposed to show in the URL in farsi. I have included a UTF-8 character set in the `.htaccess` but still nothing.

Currently my URLs look like this:

`http://www.domain.com/3/posts/4__/4__/41722__.html`

I want it to appear like this:

`http://www.domain.com/3/posts/4__/4__/41722_فروش آپارتمان نوساز.html`

I have a good understanding of PHP and HTML but I really don't understand this whole `.htaccess` and URL rewrite concept. I was hoping that someone could help me with this.

Here is a copy of my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On                                                      


AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Show ad                                                                                                                                      RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html     /index.php?view=showad&adid=$7&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Ads                                                                                                                                          RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/page([0-9]*)\.html         /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=$5&cityid=$1&page=$7 [QSA] RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                  /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=$5&cityid=$1 [QSA]

## Begin Version 5.2 - Pagination bug fix + Uniform page links ##

# Ads by cat                                                                                                                                   RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/page([0-9]*)\.html /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=0&&cityid=$1&page=$5 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                                /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]

## End Version 5.2 - Pagination bug fix + Uniform page links ##

# Show event                                                                                                                                   RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events(/(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)))?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html          /index.php?view=showevent&date=$4&adid=$8&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Events on date                                                                                                                               RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events/(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+))/page([0-9]*)\.html             /index.php?view=events&date=$3&cityid=$1&page=$7 [QSA] RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events/(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+))                            /index.php?view=events&date=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA] RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events                                     /index.php?view=events&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Show image                                                                                                                                   RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                      /index.php?view=showimg&posterenc=$3&imgid=$4&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Images by user, paged                                                                                                                        RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/([^/]+)/page([0-9]+)\.html                          /index.php?view=imgs&posterenc=$3&cityid=$1&page=$4 [QSA]

# Top Images, paged                                                                                                                            RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/page([0-9]+)\.html                              /index.php?view=imgs&cityid=$1&page=$3 [QSA]

# Images by user                                                                                                                               RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/([^/]+)                                 /index.php?view=imgs&posterenc=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Top Images                                                                                                                                   RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images                                     /index.php?view=imgs&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Quick ad/event/image                                                                                                                         RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/showpost/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                            /index.php?view=showad&adid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA] RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/showevent/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                           /index.php?view=showevent&adid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA] RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/showimage/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                            /index.php?view=showimg&imgid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# City/Region                                                                                                                                  RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                                            /index.php?view=main&cityid=$1 [QSA] RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                                          /index.php?view=main&cityid=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

For example
`http://localhost/aaraad/fa/1489820252460/خانه.html`:

```
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9-_]+)/(.+?).html/?$ ?lan=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC,L]
```

Match any character: `(.+?)`